# Ubuntu expand free disk space after RAID change

Tags: ubuntu, storage, ssd

maybe someone can advise how to expand free disk space to SDA6 part?
Before I have used 2x960GB SSD (Hardware RAID1), now I have added +2x960GB SSD and made Hardware RAID10 (1+0).
Problem is now that I see SDA shows 1.8T but I don't know exactly how to add free space to SDA6 partition. Any help would be appreciated.

SDA6 now has 800GB which was when I had RAID1, but now I need to expand it with free space add all to SDA6.

**LSBLK**

```
NAME                                               MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                  8:0    0   1.8T  0 disk
├─sda1                                               8:1    0     1M  0 part
├─sda2                                               8:2    0     4G  0 part [SWAP]
├─sda3                                               8:3    0    80G  0 part /
├─sda4                                               8:4    0     1G  0 part /boot
├─sda5                                               8:5    0     9G  0 part /home
└─sda6                                               8:6    0 800.2G  0 part
  ├─vg-vsv1009--dm3xqwu9d2jkm9dk--owmyatf934ztq1pz 253:0    0   550G  0 lvm
  ├─vg-vsv1010--dczfdc34hjryclq3--9bcnkcmj6r0taqld 253:1    0    50G  0 lvm
  └─vg-vsv1011--d07tsnzpkhav6wwl--pw2ywfybpkabegl5 253:2    0   120G  0 lvm
```

**VGDISPLAY**

```
root@localhost:~# vgdisplay
  --- Volume group ---
  VG Name               vg
  System ID
  Format                lvm2
  Metadata Areas        1
  Metadata Sequence No  101
  VG Access             read/write
  VG Status             resizable
  MAX LV                0
  Cur LV                3
  Open LV               3
  Max PV                0
  Cur PV                1
  Act PV                1
  VG Size               800.21 GiB
  PE Size               4.00 MiB
  Total PE              204855
  Alloc PE / Size       184320 / 720.00 GiB
  Free  PE / Size       20535 / 80.21 GiB
  VG UUID               6wtUB8-OaEr-iIFH-eb5D-fLzZ-4tjf-efed7q
```

Comment: You need to run `gparted`, which has Resize partition function, which expands the SDA6 partition to fill the free space. Then you can use LVM tools to increase the volume group / logical volumes.

Comment: @TeroKilkanen thanks will try it out now and let know everyone if it worked so there would be no more questions like this one again :D